# Specflow tests does not show results until finished

Tags: bdd, watin, specflow

I am running a large amounts of specflow tests that take a while to run. I have these running on a build server - and I can see the output while these are running.

```
[10:59:13][Step 3/3] Results               Top Level Tests
[10:59:13][Step 3/3] -------               ---------------
[10:59:13][Step 3/3] Passed                Project.Web.Specflow.Specs.Account.ForgotPasswordsFeature.ExistingUserHasForgottenTheirPassword
[10:59:23][Step 3/3] Passed                Project.Web.Specflow.Specs.Account.ForgotPasswordsFeature.Non_ExistingUserHasForgottenTheirPassword
[10:59:32][Step 3/3] Failed                Project.Web.Specflow.Specs.Admin.AdminTabFeature.AdminUserLoggedIn
[10:59:45][Step 3/3] Failed
```

etc.

All I can see is whether a scenario has passed or failed. I would like to see the error message when these tests fail. These error messages are only revealed at the end of the test run. Is there a way to reveal the report during the test run rather at the end of the test run? This way I can start analysing the failures rather than having to wait 30 min.

Thanks!

Comment: Which build server do you use?

Comment: Currently using Teamcity

Comment: What runner are you using to run the tests? I have had success in using the standard NUnit runner that comes bundled with TeamCity. We have one build step to build the solution, then a second NUnit build step to run the tests.

Comment: Are you using the built-in MSTest runner, or are you running your tests via a command line script of some kind?